# how to give ng-options for array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing problem with my json for binding in select tag in angular.

Json:

```
{
"List": [
    {
        "service": [
            "one"
        ],

        "id": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "service": [
            "two"
        ],

        "id": [
           2
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Here I need to bind service property in select tag. I am getting array of objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an array because each item in the main list has a `service` property and `id` property as an array, so in order to populate the list of options you need to use the following:

```
ng-options="item.id[0] as item.service[0] for item in items.List"
```

I saved the list of items in the controller using `$scope.items` and I'm referencing to it using `... in items.List` in the `ngOptions` directive.

The value of each `<option>` and the caption/label in the `<select>` element is set using `item.id[0] as item.service[0] for item` - It select the first element in each of the `service` and `id` arrays for each of the options.

Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = {"List": [
      {
        "service": [
            "one"
        ],

        "id": [
            1
        ]
      },
      {
        "service": [
            "two"
        ],

        "id": [
           2
        ]
      }
    ]};
    
    $scope.selectionChanged = function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    };
    
    // You can also define a pre-selected option by uncommenting the following line 
    // $scope.selected = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-options="item.id[0] as item.service[0] for item in items.List" ng-model="selected" ng-change="selectionChanged(selected)"></select>
  
  <div ng-if="selected">
    Selected: <pre ng-bind="selected"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```